# SQL Server : select count of newer rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table definition and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE SMSToken
(
    sessionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    token VARCHAR(10),
    destination_addr_identifier INT,
    requestedAt DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO SMSToken 
VALUES ('A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB40', 'D', 123456, '2021-01-01 00:06:01')
INSERT INTO SMSToken 
VALUES ('A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB41', 'C', 123456, '2021-01-01 00:05:01')
INSERT INTO SMSToken 
VALUES ('A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB42', 'B', 123456, '2021-01-01 00:04:01')
INSERT INTO SMSToken 
VALUES ('A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB43', 'Y', 456456, '2021-01-01 00:02:05')
INSERT INTO SMSToken 
VALUES ('A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB44', 'A', 123456, '2021-01-01 00:02:00')
INSERT INTO SMSToken 
VALUES ('A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB45', 'X', 123321, '2021-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I am looking for a solution to output only one row (sessionId = uid) and number of newer rows from list.

Example on SQL-Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57688/1/0

```
SELECT 
    token,
    destination_addr_identifier,
    requestedAt,
    --Count of Newer
FROM 
    SMSToken
WHERE 
    destination_addr_identifier = (SELECT destination_addr_identifier
                                   FROM SMSToken
                                   WHERE sessionId = 'A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB42')
ORDER BY 
    requestedAt DESC
```

Result is:

| token | identifier | requestedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | 123456 | 2021-01-01T00:06:01Z |
| C | 123456 | 2021-01-01T00:05:01Z |
| B | 123456 | 2021-01-01T00:04:01Z |
| A | 123456 | 2021-01-01T00:02:00Z |

Result should be row **B** with count of newer Rows:

| token | identifier | requestedAt | countOfNewer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 123456 | 2021-01-01T00:04:01Z | 2 |

I'm using SQL Server 2014

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery.

```
SELECT st1.token,
       st1.destination_addr_identifier,
       st1.requestedat,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM smstoken st2
               WHERE st2.requestedat > st1.requestedat) countofnewer
       FROM smstoken st1
       WHERE st1.sessionid = 'A23980FE-96BF-DD6A-91FE-C96BDBEBCB42';
```